# problems with a perl "system" script

Tags: perl, syntax

Im trying to write a very simple script that copies files from several remote computers to my computer. I've written the following in perl:

```
@Comps = ("comp1","comp2","comp3","comp4");

foreach $comp (@Comps)
{
  system("copy /Y \\\\$comp\\c\$\\myfolder\\$comp*.log   C:\\Program Files\\My Cont Folder\\input\\");
}
```

I get a syntax error and cant understand why.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Given the case that Perl is passing the characters to the shell, the only way that the shell will process `"C:\Program Files"` as one argument is to put double quotes around it. (Or sometimes just with one double quote preceding it.)

So you might need a few more backslashes (so I qq-ed it):

```
system( qq{cmd /c copy /Y \\\\$comp\\c\$\\myfolder\\$comp*.log "C:\\Program Files\\My Cont Folder\\input\\"} )
```

Comment: Looks like you've got both %s and $comp in your string.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you've got error in the command itself, because the  perl code ran fine. (Gave me 4 times "command not found" since I'm on Unix).

I would suggest using list form of system() call: `system("copy", "/Y", $src, $dst);` and, probably, even sprintf() to fill out $src and $dst.

Of course, you can always check what exactly gets executed by running `print` before `system`. I often hesitate and often print.

Answer (score 1):

Perl and windows paths don't mix very well, why not use [File::Copy](http://search.cpan.org/~jesse/perl-5.14.0/lib/File/Copy.pm) instead?

```
use File::Copy;
copy($file1,$file2) or die "Copy failed: $!";
```

And then you can use forward slash in your paths instead. Much easier.

Comment: You can actually use a proper (`/`) slash in windows paths all the time.  Even with good ol' fashioned `open`.

Comment: @daotoad Yes, I know you can in perl, but I did not know I could use them in windows cmd.